# Generating IDs within Knockout Foreach loops

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm trying to build some HTML with Knockout that Jquery UI can turn into [toggle buttons](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio). What I need to arrive at is this:

```
<div id="status">
    <input type="radio" id="status_ACTIVE" value="ACTIVE" name="status" /><label for="status_ACTIVE">Active</label>
    <input type="radio" id="status_INACTIVE" value="INACTIVE" name="status" checked="checked" /><label for="status_INACTIVE">Inactive</label>
</div>
```

Using JQuery UI I can easily turn that into toggle buttons. But how do I generate that without using the now depreciated JQuery Templates? This is what I attempted to do:

Inside the javascript model:

```
self.statuses = [{Selected:true,Text:"Active",Value:"ACTIVE"},{Selected:false,Text:"Inactive",Value:"INACTIVE"}];
```

The markup:

```
<div id="status" data-bind="foreach: statuses">
    <input type="radio" name="status" data-bind="value: Value, id: 'status_' + Value" /><label data-bind="text: Text, for: 'status_' + Value"></label>
</div>
```

This doesn't work. I don't think it likes how I'm trying to create that ID, or associate it with the for in the loop. It draws the buttons incorrectly, as two independent buttons and the click functionality doesn't work.

Even if I just specify the value as the id like: `id: Value` and `for: Value` it still doesn't work. Can I not set these attributes using knockout?

Comment: Looks like there isn't a binding for the attributes "id" or "for." I need to write a custom binding for it. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding this javascript solved my issue:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.id = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(element).attr('id', valueAccessor());
    }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.forattr = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        $(element).attr('for', valueAccessor());
    }
};
```

I did have to change `for: 'status_' + Value` into `foratt: 'status_' + Value` as `for` is a reserved word.

**Update:**
I could have also used the "attr" binding, like this:

```
attr: { for: 'status_' + Value }
```

Comment: You could also use data-bind="attr: { for: 'status_' + $index }" and data-bind="attr: { id: 'status_' + $index }" for unique IDs.  $index to refers to the zero-based index of the current array item. $index is an observable and is updated whenever the index of the item changes (e.g., if items are added to or removed from the array).

Comment: AFAIK dealing with reserved keyword issue is as easy as changing for:'' into 'for':''

Comment: The solution you added in your '**update**' is the right way of solving this. Adding an extra binding handler doesn't seem to be worth the trouble imo.